# Can I use @ngrx with vue?

Tags: vue.js, ngrx

We have a desktop app in Angular and a mobile app in Vue, that do the same thing, share apis etc. We need a (shared) state management solution. From tutorials, I can see nothing particularly Angular-specific in Ngrx, but I'm completely new to state management and RxJS. Without recommending a product, does anyone know a reason why I can't point Vue at an @ngrx store ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** . Love to be wrong.

The way you initialize a reducer is using `StoreModule` which is angular module, you cannot do in vue. The whole ngrx source code is built on angular ( using modules, services etc ). You can't run it without angular code.

Comment: It hurts me giving you kudos for bad news, but voila, this is very useful thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could give MiniRx a try... https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-rx-store
It has a very similar API to NgRx and should work with any framework.